# ObjectInputStream throwing NotSerializableException

Tags: java, objectinputstream, notserializableexception

I'm trying to read an array (called `PWlist`) of objects from a `.dat` file using `ObjectInputStream`. The array contains two different objects, `LongPW` and `PinPW`. When I try to perform the read, I am getting this exception...

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: PinPW
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1332)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at Handler.fromFile(Handler.java:99)
at Window$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(Window.java:104)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6375)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6140)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4737)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:684)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:657)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:655)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:654)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Could someone please help me understand what is wrong

Comment: I recommend less error message and more Source code.

Comment: Did you write the .dat file with an ObjectOutputStream? If not, this can't work.

Comment: You *haven't* 'tried everything' or you would have found the solution as given below. You haven't even read the Javadoc for `NotSerializableException` by the looks of it.

Answer (score 5):

`java.io.NotSerializableException: PinPW` means that class PinPW is not Serializable hence 
Mark your `PinPW` to implement Serializable

```
public class PinPW implements Serializable {

}
```

Comment: It is: 
 `public class PinPW extends Info implements Serializable {
}
public class longPW extends Info implements Serializable{
}
`